# Android call findViewById from adapter custom class

Tags: android, listview, adapter, findviewbyid

Good afternoon,

So I have a custom ListView with a custom Adapter that has an item that is a checkbox for each row. In my getView I implemented setOnCheckedChangeListener and the  onCheckedChanged handlers for my checkbox.

Now, the problem is:

Whenever I check/uncheck one of items of the list I would like to update an external TextView with the values I want (assume that for each item there is a price associated so I want to show below the list the total price).

How am I supposed to reach the "external" view from the getView of adapter? What other workaround do I have?

I leave here some part of my code on the getView function of my custom adapter:

```
CheckBox name = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.product);
    name.setText(content[i][0]);
    final View v = view;
    final int position = i;
    name.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton group, boolean isChecked) {
            setCheckedItem(position);
            EditText quantity = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.product_quantity);
            content[position][3] = quantity.getText().toString();
            Iterator<String> it = getCheckedItems().values().iterator();
            Double total = 0.0;
            for (int i=0;i<getCheckedItems().size();i++){
                Integer quantity_p = Integer.parseInt(getItem(position)[3]);
                Double price = Double.parseDouble(getItem(position)[2]);
                total += quantity_p*price;
            }
            TextView total_price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_products_price);
            total_price.setText(total.toString());
        }
    });
```

Notice the last two lines: I know I can't call the findViewById but I don't know what to do by now. Any suggestions would be good, thank you.

Comment: can put your class code and xml file here?

Comment: put your adapter class in the activity class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your `TextView` to an Adapter in constructor. After this you can have a `private static` class which will implement `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangedListener` like this:

```
private static class MyOnCheckedChangedListener 
                     implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangedListener {
    TextView myView;
    public MyOnCheckedChangedListener (TextView viewToChange) {
         myView = viewToChange;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton group, 
                                 boolean isChecked) { ... }
}
```

After this just `setOnCheckedChangedListener` `new MyOnCheckedChangedListener (myTextView)` (the one you passed to `Adapter`) and you're ready to go.

Comment: What I did was to pass the TextView in construtor and then use it whenever I liked and it just worked perfectly :D

Answer (score 2):

Put your adapter class in the activity class.
Declare `TextView total_price` in main activity class
then

```
total_price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_products_price);
```

in your on create.
Then you can access `total_price` inside  `onCheckedChanged`. Try this, it may work.

Comment: It may work but I really want to run away from that solution because it would be a mess with all that stuff mixed in a single file :/

Answer (score 0):

My could be doing like this:

1. You can pass textview reference to your adapter constructor and use it to change its value.
2. But good approach is to have a `interface` implemented in your activity and in its callback method update textview. For you adapter pass activity reference in constructor and use its reference to call `interface` callback method.

a) Have `interace` as

`public Interface UpdateTextviewInterface
    {
      void updateTextview(String value);
    }`

b) Let your activity implement this interface

`public MainActivity extends Activity implments UpdateTextviewInterface`

and override that method.

c) Pass activity reference to adapter constructor. Using activity reference call `updateTextview` method to update your textview.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a thought and theory here. But can you make a static method in your activity, where the TextView you want to change is declared at, and in that method write a code for changing your text, the way you want it to change.

And then call that static method from BaseAdapter.
I say static so you dont have to make a new instance of an entire class.

Comment: I've tried to add the static method para calling the findViewById inside of it, is not allowed. ("Non-static method findViewById cannot be referenced from a static context.")